# Combining two arrays of objects where id keys match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript question that involves combining pieces of different arrays.

I have an array of objects below:

```
"people": [
        {
            "city": "SF",
            "email": "bob0@b.com",
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "id": "1",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "city": "Boston",
            "email": "bill@b.com",
            "firstName": "Bill",
            "id": "2",
            "lastName": "Anderson"
        },
        {
            "city": "Toronto",
            "email": "ann@a.com",
            "firstName": "Ann",
            "id": "3",
            "lastName": "Kline",
        }
]
```

I also have an array of tag arrays with an id object in each:

```
[["tag 1", "tag 2", {"id": "1"}], ["tag 8", "tag 2", {"id": "3"}]]
```

The expected output would be:

```
"people": [
        {
            "city": "SF",
            "email": "bob0@b.com",
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "id": "1",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "tags": ["tag 1", "tag 2"]
        },
        {
            "city": "Boston",
            "email": "bill@b.com",
            "firstName": "Bill",
            "id": "2",
            "lastName": "Anderson"
        },
        {
            "city": "Toronto",
            "email": "ann@a.com",
            "firstName": "Ann",
            "id": "3",
            "lastName": "Kline",
            "tags": ["tag 8", "tag 2"]
        }
]
```

Is there a way to add the tags to the objects above where the "id"'s match without doing a nested loop. I have tried a couple ways but have failed.

Comment: What is the expected output and show your attempted code.

Comment: That is a very odd structure for the second array (having an ID in an object as part of an array), do you have any option to change it, or are these structures out of your control?

Comment: What do you mean with _"without ... a nested loop"_? Does this also involve array functions like `Array.prototype.map`?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have added the structure of how I would like the output would look like. It is a weird structure and ultimately I'm trying too make the tags in the array a "tags" object and combine it with "people" where the id's match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Map` object which maps each `id` with the `tags`. Loop through the people array and add a property if the Map has the current `id` as key

```js
const people=[{city:"SF",email:"bob0@b.com",firstName:"Bob",id:"1",lastName:"Smith"},{city:"Boston",email:"bill@b.com",firstName:"Bill",id:"2",lastName:"Anderson"},{city:"Toronto",email:"ann@a.com",firstName:"Ann",id:"3",lastName:"Kline",}],
      tags = [["tag 1", "tag 2", {"id": "1"}], ["tag 8", "tag 2", {"id": "3"}]]
      
const map = new Map( tags.map(t => [t.pop().id, t]) )

for (const p of people)
  if (map.has(p.id))
    p.tags = map.get(p.id)

console.log(people)
```

You can also create a version which doesn't mutate the arrays

```
const map = new Map;

for (const t of tags)
    map.set( t[t.length - 1].id, t.slice(0, -1) )

const output = people.map(p => ({
    ...p,
    tags: map.get(p.id) ?? []
}));
```

Comment: very neat, but this will work only if the ID is on the last position right?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia OP's code hasn't made any indication that it will be in any other position.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
let input = [
        {
            "city": "SF",
            "email": "bob0@b.com",
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "id": "1",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "city": "Boston",
            "email": "bill@b.com",
            "firstName": "Bill",
            "id": "2",
            "lastName": "Anderson"
        },
        {
            "city": "Toronto",
            "email": "ann@a.com",
            "firstName": "Ann",
            "id": "3",
            "lastName": "Kline",
        }
]
let toAdd = [["tag 1", "tag 2", {"id": "1"}], ["tag 8", "tag 2", {"id": "3"}]].reduce((acc, el) => {
  // build a object with id -> list of tags
  acc[el.find(o => typeof o === 'object' && o !== null).id] = el.filter(o => !(typeof o === 'object' && o !== null))
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(input.map(el => {
   // add the tags to el if tags exists
   el.tags = toAdd[el.id] || [];
   return el
}))
```

this is `O(n^2)`.. if you are certain that your array has always that object at the end, you can have a `O(n)` with

```js
let input = [
        {
            "city": "SF",
            "email": "bob0@b.com",
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "id": "1",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "city": "Boston",
            "email": "bill@b.com",
            "firstName": "Bill",
            "id": "2",
            "lastName": "Anderson"
        },
        {
            "city": "Toronto",
            "email": "ann@a.com",
            "firstName": "Ann",
            "id": "3",
            "lastName": "Kline",
        }
]
let toAdd = [["tag 1", "tag 2", {"id": "1"}], ["tag 8", "tag 2", {"id": "3"}]].reduce((acc, el) => {
  // build a object with id -> list of tags
  acc[el.pop().id] = el
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(input.map(el => {
   // add the tags to el if tags exists
   el.tags = toAdd[el.id] || [];
   return el
}))
```

Comment: OP wants to avoid nested loops and this answer has 3 levels of nesting.

Comment: You have a find in a reduce in a map. Complexity: O(m * n²). I'm pretty sure there is a solution with O(m + n).

Comment: @jabaa not i have a find in a reduce and then a map....and this ends with a O(n^2), not O(n^3), since it has only 2 level of depth

Comment: Yes, sorry. You're right. I thought `toAdd` is a function but it's an object.

Comment: @jabaa no, you're wrong, the map is subsequent to the reduce, so it's O(n^2)+O(n)

Comment: @jabaa ah ok in that case it would be yes... I'm thinking about the O(m+n)...

Comment: I think you can convert the arrays into hash maps to directly access the elements by key.

Comment: @jabaa no solution comes to my mind with that strange structure that the OP is providing

Comment: @jabaa can have that only with the invariant that the ID is on the last element of the array, but it's a very weak condition, easy to brake and difficult to debug...

Comment: @adiga yes but for the sake of the question, this makes no difference, is just to directly print the result on the console